# Does the SQL Server generate the contents for a derived table contents for every matching record in a join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, determinism

I am on SQL Server 2008 R2. I am executing the following SQL a

```
use tempdb
go
create table t1 ( c1 int, c2 int, c3 uniqueidentifier null)

go
insert t1(c1,c2) values (1,2),(1,3)
go
update t1
set c2 = 5 + c2,
    c3 = t2.c3
from t1 join ( select c1=1, c3=newid())   as t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
go
select * from t1
go
drop table t1
go
```

The result of the query is

```
c1          c2          c3
----------- ----------- ------------------------------------
1           7           D6BE2119-CECB-4413-94E4-6099E5CC9028
1           8           0BF8A3E2-4E66-4091-A1B0-4FB8E130B347
```

I was expecting the GUID values in c3 to be the same. It appears that derived table t2 is being "reevaluated" for each row in the table t1 even though it is not a co-related sub-query. Is this expected behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

You would expect the `NEWID()` to be calculated once, for the derived table `t2`. This is not the case, as it is calculated for each row of the join resultset of T1 and T2.

Simply put, for each row `where T1.C1 = T2.C1` or in other words `where T1.C1=1`.

Here is a part of a statement from Microsoft regarding this:

> Closing the loop . . . I've discussed this question with the Dev team.
>   And eventually we have decided not to change current behavior, for the
>   following reasons:
>
> 1) The optimizer does not guarantee timing or number of executions of
>   scalar functions. This is a long-established tenet. It's the
>   fundamental 'leeway' that allows the optimizer enough freedom to gain
>   significant improvements in query-plan execution....

As such the optimizer can choose the timing or number of executions, to get the best performance.

[The source of the quote and some more information and examples and the response from microsoft](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/bug-newid-function)

To explain it we best go through the query plan that is created for the `UPDATE` statement.

[image]

Right of the bat we don't see a join predicate, but simply a  table scan.
A predicate is added to that table scan, to only get the rows `where C1 = 1`

[image]

This  is the '`join`' reduced to a predicate.

After this, 2 rows are found that match this predicate, and are processed by the first `Compute Scalar` operator.

[image]

And `NEWID()` is calculated for each column of the joined table + derived table.

**A workaround**

The obvious fix is to use a variable to hold the `NEWID()` value as to calculate it before the join & reuse it.

```
create table t1 ( c1 int, c2 int, c3 uniqueidentifier null)

go
insert t1(c1,c2) values (1,2),(1,3)
go
DECLARE @test uniqueidentifier = newid()
update t1
set c2 = 5 + c2,
    c3 = t2.c3
from t1 join 
( select c1=1, c3=@test)   as t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
go
select * from t1
go
drop table t1
go
```

*If you would have more than 1 source columns (T2) you would need to store the `NEWID()` values in a temporary table or table variable*

**Another interesting part:**

> So, we have a choice: if we want to guarantee a certain behavior in
>   the presence of non-deterministic (side-effecting) code – so that
>   results of JOINs, for example, follow the semantics of a nested-loop
>   execution – then we can use appropriate OPTIONs to force that behavior
>   – as UC points out. But the resulting code will run slow – that's the
>   cost of, in effect, hobbling the Query Optimizer.

[Source](http://www.glorf.it/blog/2008/05/16/sql-talk/sql-server-is-not-aware-of-nondeterministic-functions)

By using functions we could force the optimizer to first calculate the NEWID() on the source table, before the join. But I am not able to do that on the query at hand (*probably not the query's fault*).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation Randi. Something was not working "right" in one of our stored procedures and I condensed it to the sample code that I attached. I can work around this issue by creating a #temp table. But I am amazed that M.S chose not to fix this. It is hard to think like an optimizer when writing code, though some would argue that you should.